# Multiple appending in an array - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Okey, Let me put this straight.
Following is the structure of my table:

> Table Name : user_password ;  sno int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,     password
>   varchar(20)

***Test.php***

```
<?php
include "config.php"; // database connection details stored here
$mod3 = rand(0,20);
$max_passno=$dbo->prepare("select count(*) from user_password"); //find the max. no of entries in user_password table
$max_passno->execute();
$count = $max_passno->fetchColumn();
echo "</br>total count : " . $count . "</br>";
$temp_array = array(); //initialise an empty array
for($j=1; $j<=$mod3; $j++){
    $no2 = rand(1, $count + 1); //select a random number
    echo "</br>Random no. : " . $no2 . "</br>";
    $my_task = "SELECT password FROM user_password WHERE sno=$no2";
    print_r($dbo->query($my_task)->fetchAll());
    echo "</br>";
    array_push($temp_array, $dbo->query($my_task)->fetchAll()); //append the random password to $temp_array
}
print_r ($temp_array);
?>
```

**Output Expected:**

An array containing the random passwords selected during the loop.

**Actual Output:**

> total count : 29
>
> Random no. : 3 Array ( [0] => Array ( [password] => qwerty [0] =>
>   qwerty ) )
>
> Random no. : 26 Array ( [0] => Array ( [password] => trustno1 [0] =>
>   trustno1 ) )
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [password] =>
>   qwerty [0] => qwerty ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [password] =>
>   trustno1 [0] => trustno1 ) ) )

How do I put this right? Any help Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include "config.php"; // database connection details stored here
$mod3 = rand(0,20);
$max_passno = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user_password");
$count = $max_passno->num_rows;
echo "</br>total count : " . $count . "</br>";
$temp_array = array(); //initialise an empty array
for($j=1; $j<=$mod3; $j++){
    $no2 = rand(1, $count + 1); //select a random number
    echo "</br>Random no. : " . $no2 . "</br>";
    $my_task = "SELECT password FROM user_password WHERE sno=$no2";
    $result_new = $conn->query($my_task);
    $row = $result_new->fetch_assoc();
    $element = $row['password'];
    echo $element;
    array_push($temp_array, $element);
    echo "</br>";
}
echo "</br>";
print_r($temp_array);
?>
```

This will Work!